# Using a styled component's rules within `createGlobalStyle`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

New to styled components and am wondering if someone might have some advice on how to use a styled component's rules within a call to `createGlobalStyle`?

The below example is working, but I feel that it is not a great solution as `componentStyle.rules` is not in the official api docs.

```js
// A styled component
import Modal from '../Modal'
import styled, { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components'

const StyledComponent = styled(Modal)`
  background-color: pink;  
`

createGlobalStyle`
  // this div is mounted outside of the React root
  .modal-from-external-library {
    ${StyledComponent.componentStyle.rules}
  }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if what I was trying to do was possible, but I ended up solving the problem by exporting the css from the Modal using the `css` function of styled components.

```js
// Modal.js

const styles = css`
  // styles here
`

export default styled.div`
  ${styles}
`

// ... later 
const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`${styles}`

render() { return (<GlobalStyles {...props} />) }
```